# Is it possible to identify what process is changing a file with FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: filesystemwatcher

Is it possible to use the FileSystemWatcher to find the PID or process name that is changing a file?

Comment: It's not possible to do so using the `FileSystemWatcher`, but it is possible using the security event log.  See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/18/10412074.aspx).

Comment: But, the security event log doesn't contain the process ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically determine user who last modified file on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406720/programmatically-determine-user-who-last-modified-file-on-windows)

Comment: My question is not "find user" it is "find PID."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, you need a file system filter driver to track changes with such details.

Comment: I just found [FileSpy](http://www.zezula.net/en/fstools/filespy.html) which seems quite interesting; and depends on a few different filter drivers that are includes in Windows.  I am curious if these filter drivers are, in fact, the same thing that Process Monitor hooks into.  I think I'll have to get my question answered elsewhere :)  Thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 2):

Negative. The only information you will have is the data contained in the `FileSystemEventArgs` class, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs.aspx).

This means you only get the type of change that was made, as well as the path to the file that was changed.